# Shell script output file to be saved in MSExcel

Tags: excel, shell

I have a Shell script output file

```
aa bb
cc dd
eee fff
```

and want to save this in excel sheet with two columns.

```
first  second
  aa      bb
  cc      dd
 eee      fff
```

Online browsing I found this

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=" "; print "first|second"};
NR > 1{print "$0", "$1"}' input.txt > Output.xls
```

But I do not get the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your output field separator to be a comma, and you should be OK:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=","; print "first", "second"}
    {print $1, $2}
' input.txt > Output.xls
```

With awk, `$0` is the complete record and `$1` is the first field.
Also, you don't need to skip the first line of input.

Comment: I get the output :    first, second   /n   $1,$2 and so on

Comment: Ah, of course, the `$1` field references must not be quoted. Try this version